# "Attach to process" missing from Delphi 7's Run menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have to resurrect an ancient Delphi 7 application, which means I have to use the D7 IDE.  Upgrading the project to a more recent version of Delphi unfortunately isn't an option.

My new D7 installation's `Run` menu is missing `Attach to Process`.  Aside from the missing menu item, the debugger works fine (I can debug normal Delphi executables started with `Run`).

I know D7 supported this feature (it's in the help file), so does anyone have any idea what I've missed?
The installation is Delphi 7 Enterprise (Version 7.0 Build 4.453).

Current `Run` menuitems:

- Run
- Parameters...
- -
- Step Over
- Trace Into
- Trace to next Source line
- Run to Cursor
- Run Until Return
- Show Execution Point
- Program Pause
- Program Reset
- -
- Evaluate/Modify
- Add Watch
- Add Breakpoint >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aha!

Looks like what happened is my D7 HKCU wasn't initialised correctly from the HKLM repository; my D7 installation was missing all IDE Packages, Design Time Packages and Experts.

After manually merging values from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0`, D7 looks much more familiar now.

Comment: If it solves your problem, consider accepting your own answer.

Comment: yup, but you have to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer :)